# Trouble turning off specific switches

Tags: circuit-breaker

I am trying to install new master and slave dimmers. I can't turn off electricity to specific switches. They are near other switches. Is electricity being jumped from one of the other switches? I know I can turn off the main but would like to avoid that.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you value your life, you switch off the mains to replace switches. If you can't figure out which fuse/trip each circuit is on by simple process of elimination, how are you going to work out how to correctly wire the new ones?

Comment: We'll need more information to help. Please provide details about the wiring, and photos if possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin in a properly wired panel (in the US, at least - I know the UK's ring circuits are different), there should be no reason to shut off the entire house to work on one individual circuit. In this particular case, doing so may simply hide a dangerous miswiring situation the the OP has discovered but not yet identified.

Comment: @FreeMan - I was more concerned that if the OP can't figure out which fuse it is, they're already outside their skillset & should be considering hiring professional help.

Comment: Fair point, @Tetsujin, but it could be a wiring issue that isn't OP's fault, and would befuddle many moderately experienced DIYers.

Comment: If you can't turn off the electricity, then don't do the work. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the switches are (improperly) being fed by 2 different circuit breakers and that you're being 100% correct in taking a step back and thinking about it.

If you've turned off every. single. breaker. individually and you've still got power to these switches, then you'll have to start turning off pairs to see if you can find a combination that will disable them. If you do, then either you've got a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC) - completely legal, but the lack of handle ties between the breakers involved makes it illegal and very dangerous - or you've got something unintentionally miswired and you may well need to call in an electrician to get it all sorted out.

Comment: There is no handle tie between 2 breakers, I'm just glad I tested after shutting off the marked breaker and checked against ground before digging into what seemed like cold wires.

Comment: As noted, @DominicBosco, you'll need to do some testing to see if there are a pair of breakers somewhere that control the switch(es) in question. It's possible that something got screwed up by an amateur in the past, or that it's an intentionally but improperly wired MWBC. If you can figure out which two circuits, then update your original post with pics of the panel showing which circuits are involved and someone can help you sort it.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is rather than a MWBC or inadvertent bootleg, you simply have a multiple-gang switch box with switches that are fed from more than one circuit.  This is fairly common, especially near exterior doors where you might have switches for an exterior light, one or more interior lights/fans, and maybe a switched receptacle.

In that situation you will need to shut off more than one circuit to work safely in the box, but it doesn't necessarily indicate a wiring problem.  To work safely, however, you should use a non-contact voltage detector to verify that you have indeed turned off all the circuits which feed the box before working.

A picture or diagram of the box/room would help us figure out what is happening.

Comment: It is near exterior light switch and a host of other switches. I will continue to try to find another breaker that will turn off the power. Would the 2 breakers be next to each other or is it just a hit or miss. I appreciate the input.

Comment: Depends on the electrician who wired the panel, but don't expect them to be next to each other.  There is no rule that says they should be laid out in any logical fashion, but you could get lucky. :)